# Using joint statement with ifnull function MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, coalesce

I just want to replace the reference id with name from item table in the result as I showed in last table

1st table and Parent table

| id | item | amount | tax | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 20 | 2 | Y |
| 2 | 5 | 15 | 1 | N |
| 3 | 6 | 5 | 0 | N |

2nd table and child table

| id | item | p_id | amount | tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 15 | 1 |

3rd table

| id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | mobile |
| 2 | heater |
| 3 | mouse |
| 4 | electronic |
| 5 | software |
| 6 | papers |

What I get from this code

```
SELECT IFNULL(child.item, parent.item) AS item, 
       IFNULL(child.amount, parent.amount) AS amount,
       IFNULL(child.tax, parent.tax) AS tax
FROM parent
LEFT JOIN child ON parent.id = child.p_id
```

| item | amount | tax |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | 15 | 1 |
| 5 | 15 | 1 |
| 6 | 5 | 0 |

What I want is

| item | amount | tax |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mobile | 10 | 1 |
| heater | 10 | 1 |
| mouse | 15 | 1 |
| software | 15 | 1 |
| papers | 5 | 0 |

please help me to achieve this

Comment: Your sample data doesn't match the results. With the data shown you'd get (child item/parent item): (1,4), (3,4), (2,5), (null,3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join the item table using the item ID you are already showing in your query:

```
SELECT
  i.item, 
  COALESCE(c.amount, p.amount) AS amount,
  COALESCE(c.tax, p.tax) AS tax
FROM parent p
LEFT JOIN child c ON c.p_id = p.id
JOIN item i ON i.id = COALESCE(c.item, p.item)
ORDER BY i.item;
```

(I am using `COALESCE` instead of `IFNULL`, because this is standard SQL. But you can stick with `IFNULL`, if you like it better.)